# В папке test каким образом можно запретить пользователям видеть чужие файлы на Unix

Tags: ubuntu, unix

Задача следующая, как реализовать.
Есть папка test , в ней файлы созданные разными пользователями системы.
Как задать ограничения, чтоб пользователи могли видеть и удалять только свои файлы,а файлы созданные другими пользователями были скрыты?

Comment: в одном каталоге никак. только делать отдельные каталоги для каждого пользователя. ограничить открытие файлов и удаление можно, но список все равно будет полный.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скрыть отображение чужих файлов в одном каталоге не выйдет. Но можно установить разрешение на редактирование (переименование) и удаление файлов только владельцу. Для этого используется sticky bit для каталогов. Установить его можно командой

chmod +t test

Такой подход используется в linux для каталога /tmp.

Comment: sticky bit отвечает только на часть вопроса: даст права на удаление только овнерам. Но не овнеры смогут точно так же видеть эти файлы.

Comment: @EvgeniyShubin: первое же предложение в ответе отвечает на интересующую вас часть вопроса: *"Скрыть отображение чужих файлов в одном каталоге не выйдет."*